# How do you overwrite CSS Modules in React for nested components?

Tags: reactjs

As my first React Project, I want to create a DatePicker component and I would like to use CSS Modules.

However, CSS Modules generates a unique class and I would like to know if it is possible for the user to customize a nested component for example ?

Answer (score 0):

What is a nested component in this case? CSS modules will encapsulate your styles, you can still write any kind of valid CSS in that file..